# jenkins multibranch pipeline job github pull request builder configuration error

Tags: jenkins, plugins, pull-request

i set up github pull request builder as below
[image]

but i cannot find the trigger setting in my multibranch pipeline job
[image]

what should i do?
i don`t know even what is wrong.
please help me.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this issue by install "**multibranch-scan-webhook-trigger**"

Comment: I have a similar situation. I cannot see any settings related to *Github pull request builder* in my multi-branch pipeline job.  Am I right in understanding that if I install *multibranch-scan-webhook-trigger* then I do not need *Github pull request builder* ?

Comment: @Sau001 yes, that might be correct